# Featured image in home page not showing in Pinterest sharing button

Tags: wordpress, pinterest

I am trying to show the featured image that I specify in my wordpress backend for the home page in order to share it with the pinterest plugin.

I know that pinterest sharing only works if there is a featured image to show, but still doesn't work in my home page.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify what image gets shared in the meta data. If your "WordPres homepage" contains multiple posts it will have multiple featured images. You'll need to make sure your WordPress theme has one image for the homepage. I made a special image for this scenario on my website.

For a single post page there will only be one featured image and assuming your plugins/meta data is configured correctly that should be the default Pinterest image.  Here is some info on [various competing structured meta data formats](http://blog.muschamp.ca/2013/09/25/structured-meta-data-is-sexy/). You should also look into [Pinterest's documentation on Rich Pins](https://developers.pinterest.com/rich_pins/).